# Can it be exchanged.

Tags: transactions

Can I send  bitcoins to my main bank account ,and the output is like normal cash in the bank. Rather than selling it online .

Answer (score -1):

No.
Maybe one day some exchange partners with a bank to allow such deposits. But that is very far in time...